# how to add reference to aspx.cs page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My aspx page is not wrapped in a wsp project which only a aspx and aspx.cs file.

Some function require extra dll, for example System.Linq and Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.

Therefore I add these two line to the head of my aspx.cs page:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration;
```

I got red underline and I cannot use any classes from these two dll.

Should I need to add these dll to some specific folder or any config files?

Comment: Do you added reference of those namespaces to references list? A little bit searching will reveal which DLL file names should be included to use them.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto If it is a wsp project, above namespaces are success to add and use.

Comment: You should have these added as references to your project first. Then you will be able to use them. Do you see them if you expand the References of your project?

Comment: @SmartDev my aspx page is not a project. just a aspx page in _layout folder